# Solve $y'-\frac{y}{x}=\frac{(x+y)^2}{x^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$
\begin{aligned}
y'-\frac{y}{x} &=\frac{(x+y)^2}{x^2}\\\\
x^2y'-xy &=x^2+2xy+y^2\\
\end{aligned}$$

I have no idea what is the next step.

Updated:
Let $y=vx$, which $y′=v+v′x$

$$
\begin{aligned}
y'-\frac{y}{x} &=\frac{(x+y)^2}{x^2}\\
xv'&=(v+1)^2\\
\frac{v'}{(v+1)^2}&=\frac{1}{x}\\
\int\frac{1}{(v+1)^2}\,dv &=\int\frac{1}{x}\, dx\\
-\frac{1}{v+1}&=\ln x+C\\
v&=-\frac{\ln x+1+C}{\ln x+C}\\
y&=-\frac{x(\ln x+1+C)}{\ln x+C}
\end{aligned}$$

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @Donald: **Hint:** Try letting $y = vx, y' = v + v' x$. Substitute those two and see if that makes life easier.

Comment: @Donald: Now you can verify that result. Take $y$, find $y'$ and substitute into ODE and verify LHS = RHS.

Answer (score 0):

$$ax^2+bx+c=0\implies x=(-b\pm \sqrt{b^2-4ac})/(2a)$$

substitute: $ y^{(1)}=\frac{-(3/x)+/- \sqrt{9/x^2-4(1/x^2)(1)}}{2(1/x^2)}$

solution: $y=\int \frac{-(3/x)+/- \sqrt{9/x^2-4(1/x^2)(1)}}{2(1/x^2)} dx$

Comment: I don't know for sure that this is correct.